# Linux Policy Based Routing to Wireguard Tunnel for Host on Linux Bridge

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

I am trying to use Linux routing to route traffic for a SPECIFIC IP (`172.16.20.4/32`) on a Linux Bridge (named `vmbr-dmz`) to wireguard tunnel (named `wg0`).   However it is not working.

I have two questions, firstly how to get it working when wireguard `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` and when restrcited to just `AllowedIPs=172.16.20.4/32`?

What I have done - on my host (default debian 11 installation) using linux-bridging

```
9: vmbr-dmz: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.20.1/28 brd 172.16.20.15 scope global vmbr-dmz
```

```
11: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.2.0.2/32 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I created a new Policy Routing Table in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d/dmzwg0.conf

```
100 dmzwg0
```

I create a rule for that IP address to use the table dmzwg0.  The rule is visibile in the list.

```
ip rule add from 172.16.20.4 lookup dmzwg0
```

I started with the default wireguard setup from my VPN and started using `systemctl start wg-quick@wg0`

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = k...=
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
DNS = 10.2.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 8...=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
#AllowedIPs = 172.16.20.4/32
Endpoint = NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:51820
```

I am not sure how to find the next hopw address for wg - but guessing it is 10.2.0.1. How do you determine the next-hop for a wireguard interface?  Since it is AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0 I can ping it, so I can added as next-hop.

```
ip route add default via 10.2.0.1 dev wg0 table dmzwg0
```

Looking that the `dmzwg0` table I see the route I expect

```
ip route show table dmzwg0
default via 10.2.0.1 dev wg0
```

I added the following nf table rules for masquerading.

```
nft add table nat
nft add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 \; }
nft add rule nat postrouting oifname "wg0" ip saddr 172.16.20.4/32 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
```

I started from VM I tried to connect to the internet.  On the host I ran `tcpump -i vmbr-dmz` so I could find the traffic from the bridge has the expected I address IP

```
tcpdump -i vmbr-dmz
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on vmbr-dmz, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:40:09.803588 IP 172.16.20.4.56226 > dns.google.domain: 59264+ SRV? _http._tcp.security.debian.org. (48)
14:40:09.803620 IP 172.16.20.4.55497 > dns.google.domain: 60873+ SRV? _http._tcp.deb.debian.org. (43)
14:40:14.808719 IP 172.16.20.4.41741 > 8.8.8.4.domain: 60873+ SRV? _http._tcp.deb.debian.org. (43)
14:40:14.808721 IP 172.16.20.4.54173 > 8.8.8.4.domain: 59264+ SRV? _http._tcp.security.debian.org. (48)
```

I tried tcpdump on both `wg0` and my physical NIC `eno1` and I could not see the traffic.

My nft nat rules are not counting any packets?

Q1) - So what have I missed?  What steps could I take to work out where my traffic is going?

Also if I change my wireguard config to just the IP address I want to allpw `172.16.20.4`.
I am unable to add the next hop as the host cannot reach/ping the next-hop via `wg0`.

```
ip route add default via 10.2.0.1 dev wg0 table dmzwg0
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

Q2) - How do I add the default route to the `dmzwg0` table to send all traffic via wg0 for only `172.16.20.4/32`?

Comment: AllowedIPs=172.16.20.4/32 is a single IP address, wireguard uses the first entry to indicate the endpoint, normally you would configure /32 and the /0 in the allowedips entry. You can do source specific routing by adding src 172.16.20.4 to your ip route command

Comment: To clarify ip route command on the host, not on the source itself. Sourced based routing is usually disabled because it's a security problem.

Answer (score 1):

WireGuard interfaces effectively use their own peers' configuration to determine the next routing hop, so you should not try to specify an explicit "next hop" for a WireGuard interface.

You use the `AllowedIPs` setting of each peer of a WireGuard interface to let the interface know which packets should be sent to that peer, kind of like the interface's own internal routing table. Packets that you direct out a WireGuard interface will be sent to the peer with an `AllowedIPs` setting that matches the packet's destination address (in the case of more than one match, the match with the smallest range will be selected; and WireGuard won't let you use the same exact range for more than one peer). If no `AllowedIPs` match, the packet will be dropped.

[Wg-quick](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8) will automatically set up routes to match all the `AllowedIPs` your have configured for an interface. You can use the interface's `Table` setting to direct wg-quick to set up these routes in a different routing table than your main one:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
Table = dmzwg0

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:51820
```

The above config will set up your `dmzwg0` table like this:

```
$ ip route show table dmzwg0
default dev wg0 scope link
```

To send packets that you're forwarding from `172.16.20.4` out through this WireGuard interface, you just need to add the policy routing rule you mentioned in your question:

```
ip rule add from 172.16.20.4 lookup dmzwg0 priority 123
```

Note that if you're forwarding packets *from* `172.16.20.4` to some peer through your WireGuard interface, you *do not* want to set the `AllowedIPs` of that peer to `172.16.20.4`. Always set `AllowedIPs` to the *destinations* that you want to send *to* the peer (or forward through it) -- if that includes traffic to anywhere on the Internet, it should be `0.0.0.0/0`.