# Forcing container to route outbound through VPN - source-based routing not working

Tags: routing, container, iproute, wireguard

I need to ensure outbound traffic from a specific (Docker) container is tunneled through my (WireGuard) VPN (running on my VPS) to exit to the Internet with my VPS external IP, but I am not being successful.

This is my environment:

- VPS:

  - WireGuard gateway interface on `wg0` `10.0.80.1/24`
  - Internet-facing interface `eth0`, masquerading enabled
  - IP forwarding enabled
- home server:

  - WireGuard tunnel to VPS on `wg0` `10.0.80.200/24`
  - LAN-facing interface `enp45s0` `10.0.1.200`, with Internet access through `10.0.1.1`
  - `docker82` `10.0.82.1/24`: bridge for Docker containers

    - container `10.0.82.14` that needs to be tunneled
    - Docker iptables is disabled, masquerading and forwarding is set up manually with nftables, confirmed working before what is described below
  - IP forwarding enabled

I have already tested using the VPS as a default gateway on other devices, with WireGuard's `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`, so I know masquerading and forwarding on the VPS do work.

I tried setting up source-based routing on my home server like this:

```bash
echo "100 wireguard" >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.0.82.14 table wireguard
ip route add default via 10.0.80.1 dev wg0 table wireguard
ip route add 10.0.1.1 dev enp45s0 table wireguard # needed for Docker DNS resolver
```

Inside the container (`10.0.82.14`), I do reach `10.0.80.1` but pinging a public IP results in a Destination Host Unreachable response:

```
a468bb1b5494:~# ip route
default via 10.0.82.1 dev eth0
10.0.82.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.82.14

a468bb1b5494:~# ping 10.0.80.1
PING 10.0.80.1 (10.0.80.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.80.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=9.06 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.80.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=9.28 ms
^C
--- 10.0.80.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.057/9.170/9.284/0.113 ms

a468bb1b5494:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.82.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.82.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, +2 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1016ms
```

`tcpdump`ing on `docker82` from the container host (home server):

```
laxis@nuc:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i docker82 icmp
listening on docker82, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:21:41.229730 IP 10.0.82.14 > 10.0.80.1: ICMP echo request, id 28, seq 1, length 64
14:21:41.351761 IP 10.0.80.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP echo reply, id 28, seq 1, length 64
14:21:42.231232 IP 10.0.82.14 > 10.0.80.1: ICMP echo request, id 28, seq 2, length 64
14:21:42.241748 IP 10.0.80.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP echo reply, id 28, seq 2, length 64
14:21:43.488539 IP 10.0.82.14 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 29, seq 1, length 64
14:21:43.488686 IP 10.0.82.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP host 8.8.8.8 unreachable, length 92
14:21:44.515474 IP 10.0.82.14 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 29, seq 2, length 64
14:21:44.515576 IP 10.0.82.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP host 8.8.8.8 unreachable, length 92
```

`tcpdump`ing on `wg0` from the home server:

```
laxis@nuc:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i wg0 icmp
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:23:40.848287 IP 10.0.82.14 > 10.0.80.1: ICMP echo request, id 30, seq 1, length 64
14:23:40.857968 IP 10.0.80.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP echo reply, id 30, seq 1, length 64
14:23:41.849639 IP 10.0.82.14 > 10.0.80.1: ICMP echo request, id 30, seq 2, length 64
14:23:41.859707 IP 10.0.80.1 > 10.0.82.14: ICMP echo reply, id 30, seq 2, length 64
14:23:43.230307 IP 10.0.82.14 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 31, seq 1, length 64
14:23:44.259534 IP 10.0.82.14 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 31, seq 2, length 64
```

The `wg0` interface on the VPS side sees none of the echo request packets for `8.8.8.8`.

At this point I don't understand if the custom routing table is having any effect; it looks like the network stack is somehow indeed sending the packet through `wg0`, but still internally replying as if the host is unreachable.

Does anyone have any insight as to what this could be related to?

Thank you

Comment: "I have already tested using the VPS as a default gateway on other devices, with `WireGuard's AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`, " : it's not clear if *currently* that's the case. Is it? Else can you provide your Docker system's WireGuard configuration? As well as `ip -br link; ip -br addr; ip route; ip rule`? And since it should be small, you could as well provide `nft list ruleset` so your problem can be completely reproducible.

Comment: Exactly, on my home server `AllowedIPs` of the VPS peer was set to allow only private subnets, which was the culprit! I just stumbled upon [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716681/606408) which led me to the solution, which I will now post as an answer. Thank you for you interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was more obvious than expected... I got inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716681/606408) which at the end remarks about setting `AllowedIPs` on the WireGuard peer configuration to `0.0.0.0/0`.

The resulting configuration is simpler and was even included as an example in the [`wg-quick` manual](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8): just configure WireGuard to use a separate routing table (to avoid replacing the default gateway route of the system, which I don't want in this case) and then use that table for source-based routing.

`/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf`:

```ini
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.80.200/32, fd80::200/128
Table = 100 # 100 = wireguard table
PostUp = ip route add 10.0.1.1 dev enp45s0 table wireguard
PostUp = ip rule add from 10.0.82.14 table wireguard
PreDown = ip rule del from 10.0.82.14 table wireguard
PreDown = ip route del 10.0.1.1 dev enp45s0 table wireguard

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```